# How to NOT show results from Amazon

Tags: google-chrome, search

Whenever I do a product search in Google, tonnes of adverts for Amazon come up. Is it possible to tell my search engine to NOT report results from Amazon.co.uk or Amazon.com? Using Google Chrome here.

For anyone who cares why I would want to do this, pick whichever one makes sense to you (they all make sense to me):

```
* I want to support the smaller players, Amazon crushes the little guys
* Amazon isn't always the cheapest or offer the best, they're just the biggest so their product choices shape our purchasing habits
* Amazon uses tax loopholes to pay close to zippo tax in the UK; the smaller, more honest, retailers cannot afford to pursue these loopholes
* I'm interested if this is technically possible at all
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe `-site:www.amazon.com` -site:www.amazon.co.uk`  but how to get that to default i'm not sure.. maybe a good quick way to get a custom google search page  So you don't have to type -site:... every time.

Comment: @barlop: After doing some more searches, it looks like this might be possible by logging into your Google account and customising the sites that can appear in Google Custom Search Engine. Without logging into your Google account (something I really do), it looks like it is copy-and-paste only.

Comment: you can definitely do a custom search without copy/paste, i've done  something liike it a long time ago, maybe somebody knows, .though you wanted to accept an inconvenient solution  of doing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell Google you don't want certain results.  It's not a perfect solution but it's an improvement.  Use the hyphen to exclude certain sites or words.  For example:

> Tennis shoes -site:*amazon.com -site:*amazon.co.uk

This removes Amazon sites from the search results, however, Amazon sponsored ads can still make it through, I don't think Google provides a way to exclude who you see ads from.

Comment: Make a search with just the `-site:*amazon.com -site:*amazon.co.uk` string and bookmark the results page on your favourites/bookmark bar.

Comment: I just use -Amazon.com

Comment: @Tyson: Great, even simpler! I modified that to -Amazon*, which removes Amazon.com and Amazon.co.uk. This doesn't stop sponsored adds from Amazon, but those are relatively easy to ignore (at least in Europe where sponsored adds must be clearly identified).

Answer (score 1):

just adding

```
-amazon
```

to my searches does a great job of removing the results

Comment: Even simpler than `-site:*amazon.com -site:*amazon.co.uk`!

Answer (score 0):

This gets rid of ads as well (at least in the UK), e.g. to search for *double boiler*:

```
"double boiler"  -amazon site:-*amazon*
```

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome you can use this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/highlight-or-hide-search/ilopipickdimglkalhckioobifbiinbk

and then add all domains you dont like to appear in search results to the extension.